How to make StepOver key (F8) work as expected in C++Builder debugger?
Just started using Embarcadero C++Builder 12.1 CE.
Using 'Step Over' (F8), the debugger will not step over but
will 'step into' the Assembly code.  Most annoying!
Example:  In my program, there is code like this:
Line 101    if( asNAME.Pos( "UNITYADSCACHE" ) != 0 )
Line 102    {   bIsGoodFormat = false;   }

When the debugger steps onto Line 101, all is good.
Press F8 and the debugger does not step over Line 101 onto Line 102, but instead steps like F7 into the ustring.cpp code.
What to do?

The function is probably inlined. If so, the debugger would have no idea how to step over it. Perhaps you can turn off inlining in debug builds?

What is Borland C++ 12.1? Wasn't Borland stopped in 2003 with version 6? Do you have a link to the website? I can only find this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_C%2B%2B I would recommend asking the suppot but it seems like the company doesn't exist anymore for more than 15 years.

@jabaa interestingly when I google it, I get a lot of german websites (incl. wikipedia), which write that Borland C++ is now C++builder by Embarcadero Technologies, but almost nothing about it in English. I also found it on the english wikipedia page in the section "Evolution of Borland C++".

@mch Why would you use a product name (Borland C++) that doesn't exist for over 20 years with a version that has never existed (12.1) for this product in your question? Every user, that is interested, first has to search and find out the real product name by reading the evolution of the product on Wikipedia. If you look at the other questions, tagged with borland-c++, they ask about Borland C++ 5.5 from 2000 or Borland C++ 6 from 2003.

Question lacks lots of details. More code context for shown code and function which is not step over. What is the configuration? What is the build flags? Are you sure you are debugging program build for debug mode? This kind of behavior is expected when debugging something with optimizations are enabled like debugging program build for release.

Just use vim. Nobody is using C++ Builder anymore.

I can reproduce the problem with the non-CE release of 12.1.  It seems to be related only to the Clang Win32 compiler (bcc32c), as the problem does not happen when using the "classic" Borland compiler (bcc32) or the Win64 (bcc64) compiler.
If I place a breakpoint on any narrow string assignment to the asName variable (where a temporary UnicodeString object is being constructed), then F8 will step into the C++ source code for the UnicodeString(const char*) constructor in ustring.cpp instead of stepping over it.  This is unexpected, but may be correct, ie if the compiler optimized the constructor call.
However, if I place a breakpoint on the if statement (where a temporary UnicodeString object is being constructed in the Pos() call), then F8 will step into the assembly instructions for the same UnicodeString(const char*) constructor. This is because the breakpoint has actually been placed on the 1st instruction inside the constructor, not on the 1st instruction that belongs to the if itself.  This is likely also being caused by the compiler optimizing the constructor call (?), but I would consider this a bug since the breakpoint is clearly being placed on the wrong assembly instruction.
I have reported the issue to Embarcadero:
RSS-1536: [bcc32c] Debugger steps into UnicodeString(const char*) source/assembly when user is trying to step over it

UPDATE:
The problem seems to be related to the use of the _ALWAYS_INLINE macro (which UnicodeString::Pos() uses):
#define _ALWAYS_INLINE               __attribute__((__always_inline__))

The debugger is not handling this attribute correctly when using the bcc32c compiler.
As a workaround, you can disable that macro in sysmac.h, eg:
#if !defined(NO_ALWAYS_INLINE)
 #define _ALWAYS_INLINE               __attribute__((__always_inline__))
#else
 #define _ALWAYS_INLINE
#endif

And then define NO_ALWAYS_INLINE in your project's Conditional Defines.
Embarcadero is investigating the issue.

UPDATE:
Embarcadero got back to me with some more info.
Basically, the WIN32 toolchain still uses the old Borland TDS debug format and DBK debugger, which have not been updated to support __attribute__((__always_inline__)), so the debugger doesn't have enough information it needs to Step-Over "forced-inlined" functions correctly.  Normal inline functions aren't actually inlined in debug mode, so they are not affected by this issue.  And the PDB and DWARF debug formats do contain this information.
So, that is why this issue affects only a subset of the C++ compilers.
And this likely won't be fixed in the TDS format and DBK debugger any time soon:

So this is the root-cause of RSS-1536. I doubt we will enhance tds/dbk to add this support as the goal of the team is to, eventually, move all of our debuggers to lldb. I imagine we will minimize the use of _ALWAYS_INLINE. We do not use this attribute for performance reason, but rather to avoid emitting symbols that would throw off the unit-initialization logic of C++ programs that link statically to the Delphi runtime. This issue is not relevant to UnicodeString hence we can safely remove _ALWAYS_INLINE from there. This issue affects C++ implementations of symbols from System.Types, like TPoint, TRect, etc.

It seems that disabling use of _ALWAYS_INLINE is the only way to go for now.
